# Contact webform using PHP mail() or via SMTP?

Tags: email, sendmail, phpmailer, php

I am modifying my website so users will be able to send an email through our webform.

Everything is written in PHP.

I will be using standard mail() function (PHP) and as I understand it will use local smtp server to send an email (this is sendmail, right?).

Should I maybe use SMTP server to send those emails?

I am asking because using standard mail() function it will use local server (Debian Linux 6.0) and I never really used it... I just want to be sure that all of those emails will get throu.

Comment: I recommend you to use PHPmailer or swift mailer.

Comment: I, for one, recommend you learn to use the `mail()` function properly, instead of following people's advice to "use a library for that, because you can't handle it yourself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep some standards for sending emails in mind but then it will work fine:

- set a RDNS entry for the IP you are sending the emails from
- your email server must be not an open relay
- don't send emails to users who didn't opt in to your email list via double opt in proceeder
- your server IP need to be nowhere blacklisted

If you are sending a lot of emails (like 5000 emails and more) you should use a special service for that. A shared hosting plan or a VPS won't be a good idea for that amount of emails.

Answer (score 1):

I always use PHP mailer. Its very easy to configure. Refer http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/send-email-from-a-page/using-phpmailer-to-send-mail-through-php

Answer (score 1):

Delivering mail is not an easy subject.  If you don't want to dive into it, http://mandrill.com/ is a great solution.  They offer a great free plan, and they manage all the deliverability issues for you.

We use Mandrill on all our new projects.  We were using SendGrid, which is also good, but is more expensive (and not better).

Comment: Thanks, I will look at Mandrill. I am using SwiftMailer.

Comment: Swiftmailer is great.  I use it too.  Just plug in your Mandrill api_key and smtp details into Swiftmailer and you'll never have to worry about mail again.